# how to plot scatter plot in hexagon using R or Python? ggtern or Plotly.express?

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly, ggtern

I would like to plot a hexagon diagram, as shown in the figure below, rotating 6 ternary diagrams to form the hexagon . Can someone help me? Is it possible using plotly.express or ggtern library?

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(colourpicker)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtern)


ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("TernaryPlot"),
    fileInput("csv_file", "source", multiple = FALSE, accept = "csv",
              width = NULL, buttonLabel = "Browse...",
              placeholder = "No file selected"),
    
    selectInput("x_val", "Choose x values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("y_val", "Choose y values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("z_val", "Choose z values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("a_val", "Choose a values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("b_val", "Choose b values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("c_val", "Choose c values:", choices=c()),
    selectInput("d_val", "Choose d values:", choices=c()),
    
    checkboxInput("show_point", "points", value = FALSE, width = NULL),
    checkboxInput("show_dens", "density", value = FALSE, width = NULL),
    plotOutput("ggtern")
)

server <- function(session,input, output) {
    
    selectedData <- reactive({
        inFile <- input$csv_file
        if (is.null(inFile))
            return(NULL)
        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,na.strings = c("", "NA", "#N/A"))
        updateSelectInput(session,"x_val","x series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"y_val","y series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"z_val","z series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"a_val","a series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"b_val","b series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"c_val","c series",colnames(df))
        updateSelectInput(session,"d_val","d series",colnames(df))
        return(df)
    })
    
    output$ggtern <- renderPlot({
        
        if (is.null(selectedData()))
            return(NULL)
        
        req(input$x_val)
        req(input$y_val)
        req(input$z_val)
        req(input$a_val)
        req(input$b_val)
        req(input$c_val)
        req(input$d_val)
        
    obj1 <- ggtern(data=selectedData(), aes_string(x = input$x_val, y = input$y_val, z = input$z_val)) + geom_point()
    obj2 <- ggtern(data=selectedData(), aes_string(x = input$z_val, y = input$y_val, z = input$a_val)) + geom_point() + theme_rotate(degrees = 45 )
    obj3 <- ggtern(data=selectedData(), aes_string(x = input$a_val, y = input$y_val, z = input$b_val)) + geom_point() + theme_rotate(degrees = 130 )
    obj4 <- ggtern(data=selectedData(), aes_string(x = input$b_val, y = input$y_val, z = input$c_val)) + geom_point() + theme_rotate(degrees = 180 )
    obj5 <- ggtern(data=selectedData(), aes_string(x = input$c_val, y = input$y_val, z = input$d_val)) + geom_point() + theme_rotate(degrees = 230 )
    obj6 <- ggtern(data=selectedData(), aes_string(x = input$d_val, y = input$y_val, z = input$x_val)) + geom_point() + theme_rotate(degrees = 300 )
    
    print(obj1)
    print(obj2)
    print(obj3)
    print(obj4)
    print(obj5)
    print(obj6)

    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```