# How to make a joint hexagon ternary plot in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, chemistry

I am trying to make a joint ternary plot where 6 triangular plots are put together in a hexagon shape in Python or MATLAB. I am using it to show the concentration of certain elements of a number of particles. I tried to make one in R and MATLAB, but to no avail. I would like to write it in Python. Can anyone help me with this. I have looked at previous question like mine, but I am new the programming, so I do not understand what is going on in the codes provided as answers or how to use them. I have included photos of the diagrams I am trying to make. Thanks for the future help.

I tried the previously answered questions solutions. But they didn't work. Refer to

- [how to plot scatter plot in hexagon using R or Python? ggtern or Plotly.express?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70176896/3904031)
- ['AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'colorbar'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74844424/3904031)

and the script therein.

---

Hexagon Ternary Plot:

[image: Hexagon Ternary Plot]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Overflow!* I've found this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/74844424/3904031 which shows one ternary plot. To make six, you can just make three pointing up and three pointing down and offset them (almost overlapping) by the appropriate amounts to form a hexagon. Give it a try, and if it doesn't work, add your non-working script here so the question is more specific and answerable. Stack Overflow questions generally need to be about specific problems that can be solved. *Thanks!*